# How to manage activity stack manually?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When my stack is in this situation:

```
A->B->C
```

I start A again with that is actually a single instance then stack becomes

```
B->C->A
```

I want on a button press the activity stack again becomes:

```
A->B->C
```

Comment: Can you launch in single istance B and then C?

Comment: No They are not in single instance.

Comment: then you need to clear the stack and open them again.

Comment: Yeah ok, but you can launch them again in single instance or you cannot?

Comment: Actually its not launching issue i want A to go to back to its position in stack and bring C front with B on back so that when back is pressed it will go to B.

Comment: Ok, this is not possible :)

Comment: You can use intent flags. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the activity stack directly like this, unless you want to punch it with intent flags like `REORDER_TO_FRONT` until it somehow resembles what you want to achieve.

A possible solution would be to switch to a different backstack implementation, like [Flow](https://github.com/square/flow/), because then it becomes quite easy:

```
History history = Flow.get(this).getHistory();
Iterator<Object> iterator = history.iterator();
List<Object> newHistory = new ArrayList<>();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object stackElement = iterator.next();
    newHistory.add(stackElement);
}
// reorder elements in new history
Flow.get(this).setHistory(History.newBuilder()
                                 .addAll(newHistory)
                                 .build(), 
                          Direction.FORWARD);
```